# I'm facing problem with the email program in Perl

Tags: perl

I have written a sample to send email in Perl for Windows. Is the package module am I using is right? Please help through it.I'm using Activeperl 5.It not letting me install other modules other than Email::Address.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Address;
my $to="xyz@gmail.com";
my $from="abc@gmail.com";
my $subject="Test mail";
my $message="This is the Perl mail";
my $msg=Email::Address->new(
            from=>$from,
            to=>$to,
            subject=>$subject,
            message=>$message,
);
$msg->Address;
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

Comment: What error do you get or what happens when you run this code?

Comment: Is it too hard to expect a bit more effort by your own? *"Is the package module am I using is right?"* - as you can quickly see from [the documentation of this module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Address) this is not the right module since none what you do and what you use it for matches the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

[Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Address) is for:

> Email::Address - RFC 2822 Address Parsing and Creation

And you don't want to manipulate email addresses, you want to create and send emails.

For that, you want [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or (better) [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).

**Update:**

> It not letting me install other modules other than Email::Address

If you gave us a little more detail about the errors you're getting, then we might be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

If that's the [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Address) from CPAN, you haven't done anything (And you are using it incorrectly). That module doesn't send email; it finds addresses in text.

There are various ways to send email, but you'll have to tells us more about how you'd like to send it. There are plenty of modules for SMTP and other protocols.

What's the error you get from ActivePerl when you try to install modules? Maybe we can help you fix that.

There's also [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) which comes with everything you need to interact with CPAN without going through ActiveState's Perl Package Manager.